# Rails how to disably tiny mce on text area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce

Every text_area I make gets the tiny mce editor.

How to disable tinymce editor on certain text area fields?

I have followed this installation guide.
https://github.com/kete/tiny_mce

My controller:

```
class Admin::KategorisController < Admin::AdminController
  uses_tiny_mce(:options => {  :theme => 'simple'}, :editor_selector => 'mceEditor')
end
```

Part of my form:

```
<%= f.input :name, :label => 'Navn' %>
<%= f.input :title, :label => 'URL titel' %>
<%= f.input :keywords, :label => 'Keywords' %>
<%= f..text_area :meta :cols => 80, :rows => 20, :label => 'META', :class => 'asdasd' %>
<%= f.text_area :text, :cols => 80, :rows => 20 %>
```

Both meta and text is a tinymce editor in view

If I use this in controller:

```
  uses_tiny_mce(:options => {  :theme => 'simple', :class => "mceEditor"})
```

I get this error:

```
TinyMCE::TinyMCEInvalidOption in Admin/kategoris#edit

Showing C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen/app/views/layouts/admin.erb where line #11 raised:

Invalid option class passed to tinymce

Extracted source (around line #11):

8:   <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
9:   <%= javascript_include_tag "Highcharts" %>
10:     <%= javascript_include_tag :all %>
11:  <%= include_tiny_mce_if_needed %>
12:  <script type="text/javascript">
13: tinyMCE.init({
14:         height : "50px"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tinymce only appears chere you told it to appear ie where the class is `mceEditor` if you kept the default config.

So just change the class of your text area.

EDIT:

Have a close look at this taken from the doc:

Then append the following to the text area you want to transform into a TinyMCE editor. You can change the name of the class you want to use by editing the ‘editor_selector’ param in the controller code options.

```
:class => "mceEditor"
```

EDIT2:

just keep this in your controller

```
  uses_tiny_mce :options => {  :theme => 'simple', :editor_selector => 'mceEditor'}
```

Comment: My Tinymce appear on every text_area also those that not have the class mceEditor or a class like asdasd

Comment: How should the config for the controller look like if only text areas that have the class mceEditor gets tinymce edtior

Comment: I am pretty sure that you just need documentation. There are all answers for you

Comment: in the controller: `uses_tiny_mce :options => {:editor_selector => "mceEditor"}`

Comment: I have tried it before I get an error. I have posted the error in my question

Comment: Thank you it was my tiny mce javascript that I forgot about in my layout.